# Only root in our polynomial is $\alpha$ from extension $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I  am looking for a detailed step by step answer if possible as I have an exam tomorrow a past paper questions is given by:

Let a real number $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $g= X^5+9X^3+3X-15$. Where  $E=\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$).

I have determined $\mathbb{Q}$($\alpha$) ={ $\sum^4_0 a_i$ $\alpha^i$, $i$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ }.  I.e. $a_0$ +$a_1\alpha^1$...+$a_4\alpha^4.$ I have also shown g is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, However I am unclear how to show how the only root of g in E is $\alpha$. My lecturer hinted at showing the polynomial only crosses the $x$ axis once may you expand?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: What is $E$? Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: Yes, what is $E$?

Comment: @Colliot Apologies Yes $E$ does $=$ Q

Comment: The hint is to choose $\alpha$ to be the only one real root of $g(X)$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{R}$... (now in general, telling the number of roots of a given polynomial in a number field $K$ will be as hard as factoring a polynomial in $K[X]$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = x^5 + 9x^3 + 3x - 15$.

Observe $g'(x) = 5x^4 + 27x^2 + 3$, which is always positive: an even power is greater than or equal to zero, and you are summing two even powers along with the number $3$. So, in particular, you have that $g'(x) \geq 3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which means that $g$ is always increasing.

But if $g$ is monotonically increasing, then (noting it takes on both negative and positive values) it can only have one $x$-intercept, which corresponds to only **one** real root. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be this root. Then the other four roots are all imaginary, which means, in particular, none of the four imaginary roots is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thankyou, I have another question exactly the same but the powers are different now $g= $X^193$+49X^2 + 14X + 14$ when differentiating we obtain an odd power meaning it can take a negative value, however  is it true to say due to the first term differential being so large we can neglect the fact that the second term would change the sign or am I completely wrong.

Comment: @user310686 You could make an analytical argument (or draw a convincing graph...) to show that this latter function has only one real root. But, I believe the norm on MSE is to ask separate questions in separate posts.